# How do you substract weight in weight paint with grease pencil?

Tags: weight-painting, grease-pencil, 2d

I am trying to paint the weights of my stickman, but I don't have a brush to substract the weights.
How do it do it ?
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

That's my bad since I didn't see this was a grease pencil drawing. If you go to strength from the brush settings and make it 0 then you will paint everything blue. According to blender docs blue has no value.
[image]